# Upgrade php-fpm package without restarting service

Tags: apt, upgrade, php, php-fpm

I've looked around here and the manual pages for `apt-get`, `apt`, and `dpkg`.
I would like to upgrade the php-fpm package without triggering an immediate restart of the service. I realize of course that a restart will be needed, I just want to be able to do it separately from the upgrade.

Use case: When upgrading packages and the kernel, the php webapp is interrupted twice, once when php-fpm is upgraded and again on reboot for the new kernel.

Comment: I too would be interested in a way of doing this. Did you ever find a way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this won't work. DEB packages allow to execute commands prior and after the actual installation. Restarting the service is typically trigger by a command run post installation.

When you need an uninterrupted service you may want to consider multiple servers (at least two) and a load balancer in front of them.

Comment: At the time this wasn't an option so I was hoping to find a workaround, but this is absolutely the correct answer to the underlying question.
Unless someone wanted to repackage the deb package to modify the post install script.